# How to move div from right to left on button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to make a form in which i want to display the question dynamically 
i.e if user answers the first question i want that question to be slides up and next question appears sliding from left.
here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/3466/

i don't know why the place of second div changes accordingly.

here is my jquery code

```
    $(".myButton").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'right' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = this.id;

    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changing accordingly"? It seems like your code does exactly what you want him to do. For me its hard to understand want you want to happen instead of the current result.

Comment: You will have to perform a _jquery slideup_ when the answer for the question is validated. Right now all your code does is display the 'question'.

Comment: yes .. but the sliding of a div is not proper ? if you can see div move diagonally and then to left.. i want the to be moved only right to left and not diagonally

Answer (score 1):

That's because you div `slideleft` is occurring before the `slideUp` happens and since your `divs` are not positioned `absolutely` they will take up space available in the design and once one element is hidden the sliding left `div` will take that position. Just set a `position:absolute` to a div and you can see it will come from where it should be.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hcmLw/3467/)**

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%
}
```